# Use local base for rem units

Tags: css

I have to implement a third party css file that uses rem units.

It is only used in a specific section on the site.

Is it possible to set the base for the rem only for the container div instead of the entire site?

I know that em would do this but I would prefer to leave the css file untouched

Comment: do you use rem units elsewhere ? how many selectors are implied here ?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you wrap the container that will use the third-party CSS in an [`<iframe>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). An `iframe` creates a new browsing context with its own root element, so `rem` will be relative to the font size of that root element, not your top-level root element.

`index.html`

```
…
<iframe id="that-section" src="page-section-using-third-party-css.html"></iframe>
…
```

`page-section-using-third-party-css.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="third-party-styles.css">
  <style>
    /* modify the third-party CSS here if you want */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  …
</body>
</html>
```

This does have the downside that you have to move the contained section of the page to its own HTML file. That part of the page will load a bit slower, too, because an extra HTTP request must be made for it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: it's not possible.

1 rem is defined as 1 x computed font size of the `root element`. In HTML pages, the root element is the `<html>` element, and there can only be one per window. The [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#rem) is a good read:

> **rem unit**
>
> Equal to the computed value of `font-size` on the **root element**.
>   If used in the `font-size` property of the root element, or in a document with no root element, `1rem` is equal to the initial value of the `font-size` property.

You should take up the task of modifying and adapting the CSS stylesheet to your own site, since then you know it will work as you want.